# Adjusting datagridviewcolumn size to form resizing winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 23 columns.  So a horizontal scrollbar displays to view all the columns. If I want to shrink the form itself, I want the datagrid to shrink as well with the form (with the scrollbar still present).

**What I've tried:**

```
dgvProg.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom);
```

Anchor doesn't do much because when I shrink the form, grid doesn't do anything and columns disappear as I shrink.

Doing this for each column (below) crams all the columns in the form without scrollbar:

```
 //dgvProg.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

So what approach should I take?

Comment: Have to ask why you need the columns to resize? As long as you have the scrollbars the user will be able to read the data.

Comment: @Supersnake It's just a project requirement. Consistency with the other similar applications.

Comment: @Supersnake except with my other projects, I would only have around 5 columns, so using //dgvProg.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill; for the 5 columns would work because it all fits in one screen.

Comment: My first guess would be in the resize event of the datagridview, if the height & width of the grid is within a certain range, change the column size to whatever size you prefer.

Comment: Sounds like the grid is inside another container that is NOT anchored to all sides.

Comment: @LarsTech  I guess I should have mentioned that the grid is inside a panel on a tabpage.

Comment: @LarsTech Ok so I have the grid and the panel anchored on all 4 sides.  Do I need to work with sizing the columns still?

Comment: You tell me as I can't see what you are seeing.  It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve since you want the columns to shrink, but not too much since that "crams" the columns together, etc.  Set the MinimumWidth of each column?

Comment: Why use anchors for this, can you not dock the datagridview ? In my experience docking works much beter than anchors